# Python 3 equivalent of Config module

Tags: python

[Config module](http://www.red-dove.com/config-doc/) only works in python 2.x what is the alternative in 3.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, `configparser` is the way to go then.

Comment: when i'm unsure i have the habit of posting as comment, even if it characterizes as answer, my bad.